# PostgreSQL generate characters with separator

Tags: procedure, postgresql-9.4

How do I generate `n` occurrences of a character `x` separated by a separator like `|`? I need to insert this string as an attribute in a relation.
For example, for `n=3` and `x='a'`, it should be `a|a|a`.
Using `repeat(a,3)` I get `aaa` but how can I add a separator in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could just repeat `a|` – `n` times then clear the excessive `|` character:

```
rtrim(repeat('a|', 3), '|')
```

[Working Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/0)